# A geometry problem about colinearity

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, projective-geometry

> $\textbf{Problem:}$Let $ABC$ be a triangle with circumcircle $\omega$ . Point $D$ lies on the arc $BC$ not containing $A$ of $\omega$ and is different than $B,C$ and the midpoint of arc $BC$. Tangent of $\omega$ on $D$ intersects lines $BC$,$CA$,$AB$ at $A'$,$B'$,$C'$, respectively. Lines $BB'$ and $CC'$ intersect at $E$. Line $AA'$ intersects again the circle $\omega$ at $F$. Prove that points $D,E,F$ are collinear.

[image]

I tried to use menelaus theorem on bunch of triangles and in few ways I restated the problem to apply it.But all those attempts failed.I also tried to chase cross ratios but that didn't work out either.

Any help or solution will be appreciated.

Thanks @oldboy for the diagram.

Comment: Take a photo of your sketch and add it to the question.

Comment: του? What does this mean?

Comment: And how do you define $\Gamma$?

Comment: So ... $D$ is defined to be the midpoint of the arc $BC$ of $\omega$; do you refer tho the arc containing or not containing $A$? Or do you mean that $D$ is different from the midpoint of the arc $BC$? And, if so, which arc? Please, clarify these questions.

Comment: Added picture, the statement is correct

Comment: @Dr.Mathva sorry for that.There was some typo but now its fixed.

Comment: @Yes it’s me, thanks for fixing that :) I’ll have a look at the problem in a while; let’s see if can come up with some approach. It looks difficult

Comment: @Yesit'sme you have an aops acc ?

Comment: @SunainaPati yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projective solution (or in modern contest languague, the method of moving points).

Let us fix circle and points $B,C,D$ on it as tangent at $D$ and
let us move $A$ on the circle. Then also $E,F$ and $B',C'$ moves,
but not $A'$. Then composition of projective maps $B'\mapsto A$
and $A\mapsto C'$ is also projective and this map induces projective map of
pencil from $(B)$ to $(C)$: $BB'\mapsto CC'$.

This means that intersection of $BB'$ and $CC'$, that is point $E$, describes
some conic (which goes through points $B$, $C$ and $D$). Now let line $DE$ meet circle at $F'$. Since conic and circle meet at
$D$ we see that map $E\mapsto F'$ is well defined and it is
projective from conic to circle. This also means that composition
of projective maps $A\mapsto B'$, $B'\mapsto E$ and $E\mapsto F'$
i.e. $A\mapsto F'$ is projective map on circle it self.

We want to prove that this is actually an involution of circle
$A\mapsto F$ with center at $A'$. By fundamental theorem of
projective geometry we have to find 3 particular situation for $A$
when $F=F'$ which means that $F=F'$ is always true. But this is
obviously true when $A\in\{B,C,D\}$ and we are done.

---

Any way here is an Euclidean geometry solution: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2205298p16643760

Comment: Awesome! [+1] What is the motivation behind using the *Moving Points* technique?

Comment: Well it is pretty much projective configuration, so... @Dr.Mathva

Comment: Nice solution! Other way to go is by noting that the problem is purely projective ;)